# select all or specific columns which is not in group by using pyspark or spark SQL

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to get a result set from below data. Displayed is a sample data. I am trying to get distinct value set for Name and Department. I could see several answers related to getting the distinct count but could not find one matching to my scenario or may  be somewhere I was not able to find.

```
employeeDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('1235','Hary','IT','U'),
                                         ('879','Jack','PTA','R'),
                                  ('32569','Hary','IT','T'),
                                         ('4598','MiKe','HR','Y')],
                                 ['ID','Name','Department','Tag']) 
(employeeDF.show())
employeeDF.createOrReplaceTempView("employee")
+-----+----+----------+--+
|   ID|Name|Department|Tag|
+-----+----+----------+--+
| 1235|Hary|        IT|U|
|  879|Jack|       PTA|R|
|32569|Hary|        IT|T|
| 4598|MiKe|        HR|Y|
+-----+----+----------+--+
```

So in the dataset you can see **Hary** is having 2 different id's ,So I am considering that as a junk data and I don't want them in my result set. What I am trying to achieve is a set without duplicate ID's

My expected output is

```
++----+-------------+
|ID  |Name|Department|
+----+----+----------+
|879 |Jack|       PTA|
|4598|MiKe|        HR|
+----+----+----------+
```

By running below query I am able to get below set by grouping by Name and Department, but along with that I need ID also. I cannot use ID in group by as I am trying to get distinct set of Name and Dept with unique ID

```
df = sqlContext.sql("select Name,Department from employee group by Name,Department having (count(distinct ID) =1 )")
df.show()
+----+----------+
|Name|Department|
+----+----------+
|Jack|       PTA|
|MiKe|        HR|
+----+----------+
```

Update 1
Here I have duplicated Mike's entry to make sure collect_set gets removes the duplicate id and take the count with respect to Name and Department.

```
employeeDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('1235','Hary','IT'),
                                         ('879','Jack','PTA'),
                                  ('32569','Hary','IT'),
                                         ('4598','MiKe','HR'),('4598','MiKe','HR')],
                                 ['ID','Name','Department']) 
(employeeDF.show())
employeeDF.createOrReplaceTempView("employee")

from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

result = employeeDF.withColumn(
    'count_id', 
    F.size(F.collect_set('ID').over(Window.partitionBy('Name', 'Department')))
).filter('count_id = 1').drop('count_id')
result.show()

+-----+----+----------+--------+
|   ID|Name|Department|count_id|
+-----+----+----------+--------+
|  879|Jack|       PTA|       1|
| 4598|MiKe|        HR|       1|
| 4598|MiKe|        HR|       1|
|32569|Hary|        IT|       2|
| 1235|Hary|        IT|       2|
+-----+----+----------+--------+
```

Mike 's entry is a duplicate entry with same id , so while taking group by of (Mike,HR) I need them as one entry with count 1, as the ids' are same with respect of name and HR

Expected Result

```
 +-----+----+----------+--------+
    |   ID|Name|Department|count_id|
    +-----+----+----------+--------+
    |  879|Jack|       PTA|       1|
    | 4598|MiKe|        HR|       1|
    |32569|Hary|        IT|       2|
    | 1235|Hary|        IT|       2|
    +-----+----+----------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the distinct count of ID for each name using `size(collect_set())`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

result = employeeDF.withColumn(
    'count_id', 
    F.size(F.collect_set('ID').over(Window.partitionBy('Name', 'Department')))
).filter('count_id = 1').drop('count_id').distinct()

result.show()
+----+----+----------+
|  ID|Name|Department|
+----+----+----------+
| 879|Jack|       PTA|
|4598|MiKe|        HR|
+----+----+----------+
```

Comment: I need group by of name and department. So here I will have to partition by name and dept(answer tht u hv mentioned only contains name). Np I can do that.But if there were duplicate IDs for one name ,dept (let's say Jack's record came twice with same id)combination we need to get distinct values also right so will collect set eliminate duplicates?

Comment: Yes, collect_set remove duplicate IDs.

Comment: seems likecollect_set t is not removing duplicates. updated my try in question

Comment: @UnmeshaSreeVeni sorry that I misunderstood. See edited answer. You can simply add `.distinct()` at the end.

Comment: Yes,true. Done that. But was checking if we can remove them with other options.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists` in Spark SQL :

```
df = sqlContext.sql("""
select * 
from employee e1 
where not exists (
            select 1 
            from employee e2 
            where e1.Department = e2.Department 
            and e1.Name = e2.Name and e1.ID != e2.ID
            )
""")

df.show()

#+----+----+----------+---+
#|  ID|Name|Department|Tag|
#+----+----+----------+---+
#|4598|MiKe|        HR|  Y|
#| 879|Jack|       PTA|  R|
#+----+----+----------+---+
```